# Pointers and Arrays for C Programming (basics)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int a[3];
int *p = a;
```

what is the value stored at the memory location associated with `p` is?

What is the value stored at the memory address found?

does it point to the name `"a"`
or the address of the first slot of the array 
or the value for the first element in `"a"`

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 3):

> what is the value stored at the memory location associated with p is?

It stores the address of the first element of `a`.

> What is the value stored at the memory address found?

Not clear what you mean my that.

> does it point to the name "a" or the address of the first slot of the array or the value for the first element in "a"

`p` is an alias for a location in memory. The value in that memory is the address of the first element of `a`. It does not point to name `a`.

Answer (score -1):

The name of an array is also the pointer to first item of the array.

```
a == &a[0]
```

generates "true" here.

Comment: Actually, no! An array just happens to decay to a pointer to its first element in most contexts.